# Update PostgreSQL table; insert data from subquery, on conflict do update duplicate id

Tags: postgis, postgresql, update, insert

## Context

I run into (some good old) troubles when trying to update a [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) (10.12) table called `nodes` containing nodes with some few attributes from [OSM](https://www.openstreetmap.org) + some few others.
I only want to update the OSM attribute `(lat, lon, osmid, highway, geom)` but not the few others I also have on the table `nodes`.

In order to update this table `nodes` without breaking it, I took a security margin and created an other clean table called `osmnodes` where I first fetch the OSM basic data I need (see above) using [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) (...do some pre-processing...) and, only after that, I upgrade my main table `nodes` as follows:

```
INSERT INTO schema.nodes
   (id, lat, lon, osmid, highway, geom) -- I only want to upgrade these basic OSM fields, not the others
OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE -- this is mandatory, see the note hereunder
SELECT
     b.fid, b.x, b.y,
     b.osmid::bigint, b.highway, b.geom
FROM osmschema.osmnodes b;
```

Note that `id` of table `schema.nodes` was initially defined as: `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`.

### Error 1

This obviously sends me a duplicate key error:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "nodes_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

So I naturally went for a coupled [update](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/) such as:

```
INSERT INTO schema.nodes
   (id, lat, lon, osmid, highway, geom)
OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE
SELECT
     b.fid, b.x, b.y,
     b.osmid::bigint, b.highway, b.geom
FROM osmschema.osmnodes b

ON CONFLICT (osmid) DO
UPDATE SET
(lat, lon, highway, geom) -- removed the id here as I want to keep its already present value
=
b.x, b.y, b.highway, b.geom
-- FROM osmschema.osmnodes b -- the line to be freed to get to the next step hereunder
WHERE b.osmid = nodes.osmid; -- update the matching id
```

### Error 2

Then I get:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "b"
LINE 13: (b.x, b.y, b.highway, b.geom)
          ^
```

### Error 3

And, If I add the `FROM` clause which is asked for (un-comment the line in the previous snippet):

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 14: FROM osmschema.osmnodes b
```

## Question

I'm missing something there (...), I thought I would be simple...
The [`OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-insert.html) seems not to work after it's been called.
What's wrong with my statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the `id` field, not `osmid`, so the workaround won't work.

The second issue is on the upsert. You need to refer to `EXCLUDED.` to get the provided values, there is no need to re-query the tables.

```
ON CONFLICT (id) DO
UPDATE SET
 lat=EXCLUDED.lat, 
 lon=EXCLUDED.lon, 
 highway=EXCLUDED.highway, 
 geom=EXCLUDED.geom;
```

At last, note that you have swapped X/Y and lat/long (X should be longitude)

Comment: Thanks². Didn't know about the `EXCLUDED` keyword! But a small question here; instead of writing many equals sign to assign each value individually, would it be possible to write let's say, a single "block assignment" such as `(val1, val2, ...valN) = (EXCLUDED.val1, EXCLUDED.val2, ... EXCLUDED.valN)` ? It seems yes from what I've tried, maybe you can add both solutions; I always find my self more comfortable with the second while setting *lots* of values that I copy-paste from any previous query for example.

Comment: it works for `update` so it is likely ok here too... but I haven't tried it (for lots of fields, a spreadsheet + code or an sql query will write them for me :)

Comment: Are by chance `osmid` unique? Because in my case, I'm not sure the `id`, which was set automatically, will always represent the same feature between the existing one in table `nodes` and the one coming from the `osmnodes` table. Indeed, little changes on the way I query the data may lead to a feature tagged `id=1` which is totally different than the feature `id=1` in the *existing* table I'd like to update. Hence, I'd like to rely on the `osmid` ([even if not perfectly reliable](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Permanent_ID)). I guess I have to make this field `unique` as well.

Comment: I hate this field (osm_id) because it looks unique (for points at least) and constant, but it is neither. The osm_id can also be recycled to a completely unrelated object. That being said, you can also rely on other attributes to decide if the feature is the same or not (but that's a completely different question)